# how to make values in X axis horizontal in a JFreeChart?

Tags: java, user-interface, jfreechart

I am working with JFreeChart in java in order to show some charts.
I want to make the value in the X axis vertical to save the space between two dots in the chart ( line chart ).

The picture below shows what i mean:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by x axis vertical ? Can you add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
...
XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
CategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();
categoryAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
// categoryAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
...
```